# OleDb - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'

Tags: c#, sql-server

Alright so, Im trying to do a simple update query to a table but I keep getting this error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'`. The thing is. it only goes wrong when ome values are NULL, but I've checked and IT DOES allow null values. Here is my code for the query

```
public void UpdateQuery(String[] valores) 
{
    conexion = this.Connections.OLEDBCONNECTION.ConnectionString;
    String query = " UPDATE [UTB_CUENTAS] SET CODTYP=ISNULL(?,CODTYP), CODORG=ISNULL(?,CODORG), CODGRP=ISNULL(?,CODGRP), TXTDEN=ISNULL(?,TXTDEN),"
                 + " IDEACC=ISNULL(?,IDEACC), CODAPP=ISNULL(?,CODAPP), NUMPLZ=ISNULL(?,NUMPLZ), CODCUR=ISNULL(?,CODCUR), DATING=ISNULL(?,DATING),"
                 + " NUMACCCTE=ISNULL(?,NUMACCCTE), DATCAN=ISNULL(?,DATCAN), FLGESTADO=ISNULL(?,FLGESTADO), DATELI=ISNULL(?,DATELI),"
                 + " DATUPD=ISNULL(?,DATUPD), TXTADR=ISNULL(?,TXTADR), CODUSR=ISNULL(?,CODUSR)"
                 + " WHERE NUMACC = ?";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conexion))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODTYP", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = valores[1];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODORG", OleDbType.VarChar, 18).Value = valores[2];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODGRP", OleDbType.VarChar, 4).Value = valores[3];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TXTDEN", OleDbType.VarChar, 150).Value = valores[4];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDEACC", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = valores[5];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODAPP", OleDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = valores[6];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMPLZ", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = valores[7];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODCUR", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = valores[8];

            if (valores[9] == null)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATING", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATING", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(valores[9]);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMACCCTE", OleDbType.VarChar, 18).Value = valores[10];

            if (valores[11] == null)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATCAN", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATCAN", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(valores[11]);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FLGESTADO", OleDbType.Char, 1).Value = valores[12];

            if (valores[13] == null)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATELI", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DBNull.Value;
            else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATELI", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(valores[13]);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATUPD", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(valores[14]);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TXTADR", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = valores[15];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODUSR", OleDbType.VarChar, 7).Value = valores[16];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMACC", OleDbType.VarChar, 18).Value = valores[0];

            cmd.CommandText = query;
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex) 
            {
                byte[] emptybytes = new byte[0];

                this.Log("CustomMessage: Error en NUMACC: " + valores[0] + " | " + ex.Message, 0, emptybytes);
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I have given the "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format for the datetime column. It works when I do it from SQl Server Management Studio, but thats it. Now, I know OLEDB doesnt really care about parameter name, it works on the same order is called in the query. Thats why I did it this way.

I've testing with just using

```
String query = " UPDATE [UTB_CUENTAS] SET CODTYP=ISNULL(?,CODTYP) WHERE NUMACC = ?"
```

and only using the first parameter and it works! but using the second value CODORG it throws the error.

In this case, `valores[2]` and `valores[3]` are null values, but since Im using `ISNULL()` in the query, I believe it shouldnt be a problem. Even if it is, the column allow null values, but its not updating

Comment: None of your code has the word "DEFAULT" in it...you aren't showing the right code.

Comment: well thats the thing. I haven't written DEFAULT anywhere

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Right here `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Its when it tries to execute the query

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the `UTB_CUENTAS` table?  An update trigger could be executing a statement which as a syntax error in it...

Comment: I do actually, a `TRIGGER FOR UPDATE` but since I was able to do the update inside Management Studio I didnt think that was the problem

Comment: If you put a break point after the line where you assign the query to `query`, then copy the contents of `query` and paste into management studio, does it run fine?

Comment: yes it does, I have already done that

Comment: null and DBNull.Value are different things. Try `cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODORG", OleDbType.VarChar, 18).Value = valores[2] ?? (object)DBNull.Value;`

Comment: @LarsTech I've tried but still get the same error

Comment: Did you test that on the smaller test query you mentioned?  If not that, then you would have to double check the database column settings.  It's really the only places that could cause this error.

Comment: @LarsTech THANK YOU, It worked! Im so dumb cuz I actually did it on the datetime parameters but not on the rest thinking null value was the same for varchar type in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, null and DBNull.Value are different things. Try

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODORG", OleDbType.VarChar, 18).Value = valores[2] ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: But now comes another question. I did an insert query aswell and its working fine, but I didnt use `DBNull.Value` on String parameters. Only used it when datetime was null. How did it work there, and not on the update query? Does OleDb manages both different?

Comment: @Mokz Don't know for sure, but the Insert might have used the "Default" value of the column, whereas an Update won't use that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the WHERE clausole dinamically, check in the program the value, if is null dont add to query string the sql code for the value and dont add parameter to command

Comment: That parameter will never have a null value, already did the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I meant creates sql string dinamically in that way...

```
String SQLquery = " UPDATE [UTB_CUENTAS] SET ";

if (valores[1] != null)
{
    SQLquery = SQLquery + " CODTYP=?, " +
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CODTYP", OleDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = valores[1];
}
```

.... so for all the value,
and finally

```
//REMOVE THE LAST COMMA
SQLquery = SQLquery.Substring(0,SQLquery.lenght -2) + " WHERE NUMACC = ? "
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMACC", OleDbType.VarChar, 18).Value = valores[0];

cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and also the processing is optimized

Comment: Was your intention to edit your other answer?  There is an edit link for that.